# Battery voltage drop during discharge

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging, current-measurement

I have a 4.2 V, 2 Ah Li-ion battery.

Just to understand how the battery behaves when discharging, I connected the 4.2 V Li-ion battery across this [DC electronic load](https://docs.rs-online.com/ebec/A700000006465593.pdf) and set the current limit to 500 mA on the electronic load.

When I turned on the DC load, I saw the voltage on the electronic load to be around 2.4 V while discharging and the current consumed by the load is 500 mA.

I was confused. This should not happen, right?

The battery voltage should be constant right since the current limit is less than 2 Ah (the battery capacity.) Maybe I would have accepted the 2.4 V if the current was set more than 2 A, but that is not the case.

Please let me know whether this behavior is correct or if there's something wrong with my understanding.

Comment: `I saw the voltage on the electronic load` so you're talking about the voltage seen **on the load's display**, not on the battery. Two things: 1) improper connection between the source and load brings high resistance therefore high voltage drop. If the wires are thin and the connections are poor then it's normal to see some drop. *I'm testing my own design 12V/42A power supply with an electronic load, and when I overload it by 15% the voltage I see on the load's display is 11.65V.* Check your connections, and the load's configuration, and battery voltage. 2) The load/display might be faulty.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, thank you for your clarification. So, you mean to say that we should see the 4.2V only even when the battery is discharging at either 500mA or 2A, right? Also, the batter voltage would decrease from 4.2V if the current exceeds 2A, right?

Comment: You may see some drop **across the battery** due to its internal resistance. Depending on the conditions (temperature and discharge current) this drop may vary but won't be in volts level. Note that I'm talking about the voltage seen **across the battery**, not an external equipment connected through wires.

Comment: Thank you @RohatKılıç

Comment: A cell/"battery" most likely isn't rated for current ("2 A"). Your battery may be rated 2 **Ah** (Ampere-*hour*s), or, e.g, 1 Ah and "2C": twice the current that would discharge the fully charged battery in one hour (as if capacity was specified for one-hour discharge). And 4.2 V is the cut-off voltage when charging fast - dropping fast to about 3.6 V when significantly loaded, and slower from there to discharge cut-off.

Comment: @greybeard, yes, I was meaning that only. 2Ah. Let me edit that in the question. So, when the discharge rate is above 1C, does the battery voltage drop?

Comment: Read the datasheet. Proper ones will have discharge curves for various C values.

Comment: In your question, mention the "State of Charge" (SoC) along with voltages and currents. If unknown, charge fully and repeat experiment.

Comment: Exactly which "4.2 V, 2 Ah" Li-ion battery do you have?

Comment: You don't show what circuitry or wiring is between the battery and electronic load and whether the battery voltage really drops or if it drops on the way to the electronic load